# Why do I need to connect to a VPN to use SSH outside of work?

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, ssh, vpn

I am new to using ssh & vpn on ubuntu 18.04. I have a remote server at my university which I would like to connect to using my own laptop. The steps involved are (mentioned on my university's website): (1) Connect to my university's VPN and then use the ssh command using my log in credentials. It does work and I am able to ssh to the remote server. But I am curious as to why there is a need to connect to a VPN first before using ssh? 
So in the future if I would like to connect to a remote server (of an organization), do I always need to connect to a VPN as the first step? 
It would be really helpful if you could give me a brief explanation of this or redirect me to some resources! I tried googling this but a lot of complex articles popped up which I could not understand.

Comment: Please accept the best answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will indicate your problem is solved and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you will be able to ssh into the server directly, or need to connect to VPN first, it depends on how the organization has configured their network.

If the network is configured so that the ssh service on the server is exposed directly to Internet (which in fact is standard on many universities I had contact with - at least their "main" server which provides eg. email for employees is available directly via ssh), then you will be able to log in directly via ssh without the need to VPN first. On the other hand, if the network is configured so that ssh service is available only for internal network, you need to first connect to VPN.

I don't think that the second approach (with the need to connect to VPN first) is more secure than the first one, because ssh connection is encrypted by itself, and normally the server should use the same company-wide single sign-on authentication as the VPN uses, which means if you know the credentials to ssh into the server, you also know the credentials to login to VPN, and vice versa. However, some network administrators prefer that approach.

Comment: ah I see! It only depends on how the organization has configured the settings, so it is not a requirement. Interesting! and good to know. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard way to set up a secure connection from your computer (or network) to a remote network. The VPN (Virtual Private Network) establishes a encrypted connection, giving an extra layer of security and authentication, so the university network and servers aren't exposed directly to the internet.

Basically your computer becomes a part of the university network when the VPN connection is established.

Comment: Oh, so this is done to add more security but is not necessary for ssh?

Comment: Exactly.  If your computer and server are om the same network, ssh can connect directly.

Comment: Usually, for security reasons, ssh is reachable only from your companies / universities network only and not from the internet. And then you need VPN. But it's not about the security of your connection, that is good enough with SSH but a measurement against attacks from the internet

Comment: I see, thank you guys!